# Clone form fields with value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone a form, along with its respective fields values. However, I am getting one field value in all cloned fields.

```
var $couriers = $('#do-list');
$('.add-do-list').click(function( e ) {

    var $cloneElem = $couriers.children('.myform').last().clone();

  $cloneElem.find('select').attr('value', $('select').val()).end()
  $cloneElem.find('input[type=text]').attr('value', $('input[type=text]').val()).end()
  $cloneElem.find('textarea').attr('value', $('textarea').val()).end()
  $cloneElem.insertAfter( $couriers.children('.myform').last() );

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="do-list">
<li class="myform">
<form>
<input type="text" name="fname" value="to be clone" />
<input type="text" name="lname" value="to be clone" />
<textarea name="detail">to be clone</textarea>
</form>
<div class="add-do-list">Duplicate form</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code is missing something at the first `.find()`.

Comment: No it is complete code i can't see anything missing.

Comment: No, it's a [SyntaxError: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `.`](http://jsfiddle.net/7WQPG/).

Comment: Definitely a parse error, as the console would confirm.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: I have added my HTML now.

Comment: fixed the code for your review and try that first, post if it still doesn't work @Ask4Tec

Comment: You ***still*** have the same syntax error.

Comment: Here is the fiddle URL http://jsfiddle.net/chirohorit/PJZn8/

Answer (score 0):

First line, you have `,` after `$('#do-list')`. There needs to be a semi-colon or `;`.

Before the first `.find`  you need `$cloneElem` for it find inside.

Try this:

```
var $couriers = $('#do-list');
$('.add-do-list').click(function( e ) {

    var $cloneElem = $couriers.children('.myform').last().clone();

  $cloneElem.closest('select').attr('value', $('select').val()).end()
  .closest('input[type=text]').attr('value', $('input[type=text]').val()).end()
  .closest('textarea').attr('value', $('textarea').val()).end()
  .insertAfter( $couriers.children('.myform').last() );

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**UPDATE**

Replaced `.find()` with `.closest()`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P3U2Y/2/)**

Comment: The use of `.end()` means the OP is using chaining and going back one selection set. The re-use of `$cloneElem` is not needed.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Kinda confused about the use of `chaining` here but yes you are right about the re-use of `$cloneElem`... Updated it!

Comment: It has the same issue not fixed.
in your fiddle demo if you enter the text in first field and then duplicate you'll get first field value in both cloned text field.

Comment: no your solution didn't work.
i excluded the code of input textarea and select to clone and simply cloned the form holding these fields and it start working as i was looking for.
Thanks for your efforts.